# In R, gsub & Regex lookahead or lookbehind expression to remove everything BEFORE a string pattern?

Tags: regex, r, gsub, regex-lookarounds

In R I have a data frame with a column where each row has repeating text that I would like to remove that matches a specific pattern:

```
x <- c("DOI: 10.5256/f1000research.6541.r7660 The revised article answers most of my remarks and questions in a ... Continue reading The revised article answers most of my remarks and questions in a satisfactory way.", 
"DOI: 10.5256/f1000research.6601.r7701 The revision ... Continue reading The revision is approved I have read this", 
"DOI: 10.5256/f1000research.6599.r7859 I have read the revised article by Horrell and D'Orazio. They have responded appropriately to ... Continue reading I have read the revised article by Horrell and D'Orazio. They have responded appropriately to the concerns/questions raised")
```

What is a function that I could use to remove everything before `... Continue reading`  or `Continue reading` including `... Continue reading`  or `Continue reading`?

Comment: Can your strings contain newlines? See [this demo](http://ideone.com/m6rgWj). Use something like `gsub("^[\\s\\S]*[.]{3}\\s*Continue reading\\s*", "", x, perl=T)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should remove everything before `Continue reading`

```
sub('.*\\.{3}\\s*(Continue reading.*)$', '\\1', x)
```

If you need to remove characters before `... Continue reading`

```
sub('.*(\\.{3}\\s*Continue reading.*)$', '\\1', x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sub

Including continue reading,

```
sub(".*Continue reading", "", x)
```

Not including continue reading.

```
sub(".*(?=\\bContinue reading)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

or

```
sub(".*\\b(Continue reading)", "\\1", x)
```